# Can a landlord in Massachusetts charge a “landlord fee”? What might this fall under?

Tags: landlord, tenant, fees, tenancy-rules, residency

I’m looking at some places to rent in Massachusetts and I came across one that asks for first month’s rent ($750), a security deposit ($725), and a reputably low “landlord fee” ($365). I thought I saw somewhere that such fees were illegal, at least in Boston, but now I’m struggling to find anything with the same terminology. Is it legal? Could they be using an unusual name for a different fee? 
I’m not very knowledgeable about anything of this sort, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this from a landlord or a licensed broker? Landlords are quite limited in the fees they can charge. Licensed brokers can charge fees to help find a place.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it’s from a landlord, not a broker.